# why my inner join query didn't work

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have two tables in my mySql DB named brand & model.

I want to read all of brand names and count of their models in medel table.

this is my own query :

```
SELECT brand.id, brand.name AS brandName, model.name AS modelName, count(model.id) AS count
FROM carBrand brand
INNER JOIN carModel model ON model.brandId = brand.id
```

this query den't return that i want. it just return a brand name and count of all models in table

Comment: you didn't put in a group by clause, and you're mixing grouped and ungrouped fields, so.. yeah. you WILL get wonky results.

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by the data in your `carBrand` table to get the count of each one

```
SELECT brand.id, brand.name AS brandName,
       count(model.id) AS count 
FROM carBrand brand 
INNER JOIN carModel model ON model.brandId = brand.id
GROUP BY brand.id, brand.name
```

Aggregate functions like `count()`, `sum()`, ... return just a single result for the table. If you want a group-wise result then you have to group your data.

The problem with MySQL is that your query did return something. Other DB engines just through an error.

Answer (score 0):

`COUNT()` automatically groups the results. Split into two queries - one for brands and one for the count of models.